# Wordpress migration fail

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, ftp, migration

I want to migrate wordpress to new host and new domain.
Could you please let me know why I have this message?

"Apache is functioning normally"

https://preloved-bazaar.stilgut.pl/

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Install all in one migration plugin on your WordPress create a backup file of your WordPress and upload it on your domain WordPress plugin it would automatically migrate your file to the specified domain

Answer (score -1):

Because your are using a SSL Certificate and there are pages linked with http or you have not installed and configured your SSL certificate correctcly.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So why when I'm using http protocol website doesn't work (error 500)

Comment: This is a random guess. There's no way of knowing if this is the case. Many misconfigurations could lead to this output.